Unable to create an enrollment token in ElasticSearch
I am new to ELK Stack and I am setting up ELK Stack on my Windows system directly for practice. I executed the command to run elasticsearch.bat and it is working as expected on localhost:9200. Now i have to run Kibana and it requires an enrollment token. But whenever i try to run the command i get an error with exit code 73.
whenever i generate an enrollment token from elasticsearch using this command elasticsearch-create-enrollment-token -s node, it gives me the following error:
C:\elk\elasticsearch-8.13.4\bin>elasticsearch-create-enrollment-token -s node
Unable to create enrollment token for scope [node]

ERROR: Unable to create an enrollment token. Elasticsearch node HTTP layer SSL configuration is not configured with a keystore, with exit code 73

